# Not able to configure databricks with external hive metastore

Tags: azure-databricks

I am following this document https://docs.databricks.com/data/metastores/external-hive-metastore.html#spark-configuration-options
to connect to my external hive metastore. My metastore version is 3.1.0 and followed the document.

docs.databricks.comdocs.databricks.com
External Apache Hive metastore — Databricks Documentation
Learn how to connect to external Apache Hive metastores in Databricks.
10:51
I have getting this error when trying to connect to external hive metastore

```
org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf when creating Hive client using classpath: 
Please make sure that jars for your version of hive and hadoop are included in the paths passed to spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars
```

spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars=/databricks/hive_metastore_jars/*

When I do an ls on /databricks/hive_metastore_jars/, I can see all copied files
10:52
Do I need to copy any hive specific files and upload it in this folder?

I did exactly what was mentioned in the site

These are the contents of my hive_metastore_jars

```
total 56K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Mar 24 05:06 1585025573715-0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Mar 24 05:06 d596a6ec-e105-4a6e-af95-df3feffc263d_resources
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Mar 24 05:06 repl
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Mar 24 05:06 spark-2959157d-2018-441a-a7d3-d7cecb8a645f
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Mar 24 05:06 root
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Mar 24 05:06 spark-30a72ee5-304c-432b-9c13-0439511fb0cd
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Mar 24 05:06 spark-a19d167b-d571-4e58-a961-d7f6ced3d52f
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5.5K Mar 24 05:06 _CleanRShell.r3763856699176668909resource.r
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 9.7K Mar 24 05:06 _dbutils.r9057087446822479911resource.r
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  301 Mar 24 05:06 _rServeScript.r1949348184439973964resource.r
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.5K Mar 24 05:06 _startR.sh5660449951005543051resource.r
```

Am I missing anything?

Strangely If I look into the cluster boot logs here is what I get

```
20/03/24 07:29:05 INFO Persistence: Property spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName unknown - will be ignored
20/03/24 07:29:05 INFO Persistence: Property spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL unknown - will be ignored
20/03/24 07:29:05 INFO Persistence: Property spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName unknown - will be ignored
20/03/24 07:29:05 INFO Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
20/03/24 07:29:05 INFO Persistence: Property spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword unknown - will be ignored
20/03/24 07:29:05 INFO Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
20/03/24 07:29:05 INFO Persistence: Property datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll unknown - will be ignored

20/03/24 07:29:09 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
20/03/24 07:29:09 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
```

I have already set the above configurations and it shows in the logs as well

```
20/03/24 07:28:59 INFO SparkContext: Spark configuration:
spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword=*********(redacted)
spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=*********(redacted)
spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName=*********(redacted)
```

Also version information is available in my hive metastore, I can connect to mysql and see it it shows
SCHEMA_VERSION : 3.1.0
VER_ID = 1

Answer (score 0):

From the output, it looks like the jars are not copied to the "/databricks/hive_metastore_jars/" location. As mentioned in the documentation link you shared:

1. Set spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars set to maven
2. Restart the cluster with the above configuration and then check in the Spark driver logs for the message :

```
17/11/18 22:41:19 INFO IsolatedClientLoader: Downloaded metastore jars to <path>
```

From this location copy the jars to DBFS from the same cluster and then use an init script to copy the jars from DBFS to "/databricks/hive_metastore_jars/"

Comment: I did that. I have also added the output of list for that folder. These were the only jars that were there in the <path> and copied to the hive_metastore_jars folder

Comment: How do I verify that the correct jars are present in the folder?

Answer (score 0):

As I am using azure mysql there is one more step I need to perform
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/metastores/external-hive-metastore